# Acer 5738, Windows 7 random shutdowns

Tags: windows-7, troubleshooting, crash, event-viewer

I can run my computer any number of hours continuously without any issue, but if I do a Skype video call (not just audio, never happens with audio call), some flash games, or even certain online streaming, the computer just crashes with the following data from Event Viewer:

> Event 6008, The previous system shutdown at 9:37:15 AM on ‎12/‎14/‎2013 was unexpected.

with the following XML data:

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="EventLog" /> 
  <EventID Qualifiers="32768">6008</EventID> 
  <Level>2</Level> 
  <Task>0</Task> 
  <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2013-12-14T04:09:44.000000000Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>482889</EventRecordID> 
  <Channel>System</Channel> 
  <Computer>******</Computer> 
  <Security /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data>9:37:15 AM</Data> 
  <Data>‎12/‎14/‎2013</Data> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data>8347</Data> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data /> 
  <Binary>DD070C0006000E00090025000F002C03DD070C0006000E00040007000F002C03600900003C000000010000006009000000000000B0040000010000002A7F0000</Binary> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

Can anybody point out some issue here?

Comment: Troubleshoot possible overheating due to aluminum cooling fins blocked by dust and debris. Install [SpeedFan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php) and monitor your computer's voltages, fan speeds and temperatures.

Comment: @karel, Good, I placed the machine slightly raised, and the problem seems to have gone.....thank you for pointing in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Troubleshoot possible overheating due to heat sink's aluminum cooling fins blocked by dust and debris. Install [SpeedFan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php) and monitor your computer's voltages, fan speeds and temperatures. If the speed of a fan is slower than normal and that fan is spinning all the time, this is a good indication that the fan is starting to wear out due to friction on the bearings.

If a heat sink is clogged by dust and debris, it can be cleaned using canned air by a computer repair technician. This is not such an easy job to do yourself due to the difficulty of disassembling the laptop to get to the heat sink and then reassembling it.

Answer (score 0):

This particular model (5738) has a vent on the base which got blocked by some cloth. So the solution is to leave that area free from obstructions.